# Select records that do not have associations outside a certain list

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mySQL table of `nodes` and each node can be associated with many `categories`.  I have a list of category ids that are acceptable (498, 499).  I want to select only nodes who do not have categories that are not in the list of acceptable category ids.

In this example, I should get Toby and Joseph back, but not Susan...

[image]

I was initially trying this, but the `IN` clause does not exclude other categories:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, category.dir_phys_category_tid
FROM node AS n
INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category   AS category   ON n.nid = category.entity_id
WHERE n.type = 'dir_physicians'
 AND n.`status` = 1
 AND category.dir_phys_category_tid IN ( 498,499 )
```

**Answer**: modified from RolandoMySQLDBA's answer below, with formatting & naming changes

```
SELECT desired_categories.* 
FROM
    ( SELECT nid, title, COUNT(1) AS all_categories 
        FROM node 
        INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category AS category ON node.nid = category.entity_id
        GROUP BY nid
    ) AS A 

INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT nid, COUNT(1) AS good_categories 
        FROM node
        INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category AS category ON node.nid = category.entity_id
        WHERE category.dir_phys_category_tid IN (498,499) 
        GROUP BY nid
    ) AS B USING (nid)

INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT nid, title 
        FROM node 
    ) AS desired_categories USING (nid)

WHERE all_categories = good_categories;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Have you tried writing a query?

Comment: updated question. using MySQL.

Comment: Do you want all the depicted Toby and Joseph records back, or just once each?  Or should I ask: Do you want NONE of Susan's records to show, or just the one not shown?

Comment: NONE of Susan's records.  I want only people who *do not* have categories outside my 'acceptable' categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query

```
SELECT C.* FROM
(SELECT nid,COUNT(1) fullcount 
  FROM node 
  INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category   AS category   ON node.nid = category.entity_id
  GROUP BY nid) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT nid,COUNT(1) goodcount 
  FROM node
  INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category   AS category   ON node.nid = category.entity_id
  WHERE dir_phys_category_tid IN (498,499) GROUP BY nid) B USING (nid)
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT nid,title FROM node) C USING (nid)
WHERE fullcount=goodcount;
```

First, let's make some sample data. 
**NOTE: this uses a single table.  The OP used two tables - mine is intended to demonstrate the method used to count categories, which is the central part of my answer.**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS doub1ejack;
CREATE DATABASE doub1ejack;
USE doub1ejack
CREATE TABLE node
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nid INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(20),
    dir_phys_category_tid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO node (nid,title,dir_phys_category_tid) VALUES
(1171,'Toby',499),(1172,'Susan',500),(1172,'Susan',499),
(1172,'Susan',498),(1173,'Joseph',499),(1173,'Joseph',498);
SELECT * FROM node;
```

Let's load it

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS doub1ejack;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE doub1ejack;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE doub1ejack
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE node
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     nid INT NOT NULL,
    ->     title VARCHAR(20),
    ->     dir_phys_category_tid INT NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO node (nid,title,dir_phys_category_tid) VALUES
    -> (1171,'Toby',499),(1172,'Susan',500),(1172,'Susan',499),
    -> (1172,'Susan',498),(1173,'Joseph',499),(1173,'Joseph',498);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Let's look at it

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM node;
+----+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id | nid  | title  | dir_phys_category_tid |
+----+------+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | 1171 | Toby   |                   499 |
|  2 | 1172 | Susan  |                   500 |
|  3 | 1172 | Susan  |                   499 |
|  4 | 1172 | Susan  |                   498 |
|  5 | 1173 | Joseph |                   499 |
|  6 | 1173 | Joseph |                   498 |
+----+------+--------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Next, let's run the proposed query

```
mysql> SELECT C.* FROM
    -> (SELECT nid,COUNT(1) fullcount FROM node GROUP BY nid) A
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT nid,COUNT(1) goodcount FROM node
    -> WHERE dir_phys_category_tid IN (498,499)
    -> GROUP BY nid) B USING (nid)
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT DISTINCT nid,title FROM node) C USING (nid)
    -> WHERE fullcount=goodcount;
+------+--------+
| nid  | title  |
+------+--------+
| 1171 | Toby   |
| 1173 | Joseph |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK why does it work ? Let's add the count columns, remove the WHERE and see

```
mysql> SELECT C.*,fullcount,goodcount FROM
    -> (SELECT nid,COUNT(1) fullcount FROM node GROUP BY nid) A
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT nid,COUNT(1) goodcount FROM node
    -> WHERE dir_phys_category_tid IN (498,499)
    -> GROUP BY nid) B USING (nid)
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT DISTINCT nid,title FROM node) C USING (nid)
    -> ;
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| nid  | title  | fullcount | goodcount |
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1171 | Toby   |         1 |         1 |
| 1172 | Susan  |         3 |         2 |
| 1173 | Joseph |         2 |         2 |
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the correlation: When the number of categories (fullcount) is equal to the number of categories which are 498 and/or 499 (goodcount), then that row's nid is acceptable.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Wait... how do we know if the `node` table has a `dir_phys_category_tid` field?

Comment: I had to add `INNER JOIN field_data_dir_phys_category AS category ON node.nid = category.entity_id` after `(SELECT nid,COUNT(1) goodcount FROM node...`, but then it seems to work.

Comment: `node` and `categories` are different tables - a structure imposed by the CMS I'm working in (drupal)

Comment: I was just using the sample to demonstrate picking up the counts in subqueries.

Comment: Yeah, I picked up on the same.  @doub1ejack, could you please edit the scripts in Rolando's answer with the changes you have had to make for it to work? In case someone ever comes back and wants to use this post?

Comment: Ok, yeah I see what you're doing now. Nice. I'm not familiar with the `USING` keyword - what would this look like using `ON` instead?

Comment: USING is just a fancy way to do ON expr = expr. Let me tweek it.

Comment: I am sorry I am not a Drupal expert. I hope the example I provided helped.

Comment: very helpful, thank you. I need to extend this query a little further, but I thought a new post would be appropriate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/how-to-add-additional-tables-fields-into-a-query-with-multiple-inner-joins.